# Do I need to download google service json file everytime I add sha key in firebase?

Tags: flutter, firebase

I am releasing the app as firebase as it's backend. First while setting up firebase, I just added sha1 debug key and downloaded google service json file. Now my question is that if I now add release key in firebase, do I need to download google service json file again and put it into my project or the initial google service json file in my project works fine.

Answer (score 2):

you have to download the google service json file again after registering your app as a release key in firebase.